# how to Remove "SEE ALL" Filter from WordPress portfolio JavaScript or CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I have a website. In the Filtarable portfolio section, i want to hide SEE ALL option. But the only problem is when the site load it's showing ALL images from all Category. www.100pour100conceptrenovation.com/ this is the link.

```js
(function(j){
    j('.portfolio-filter a').click(function(){
        j('.da-thumbs > *').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
        j('.da-thumbs > '+ this.getAttribute('data-filter') ).addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
    })
})(jQuery)
```

```css
.portfolio-filter li:nth-child(1) {
    display:none !important;
visibility: hidden !important;
filter: none !important;
}
.portfolio-filter li:nth-child(1) a {
filter: none !important;
}
```

Now, I want to prevent All Images which are loading first.

Comment: If it is in WordPress then it should have an option of `the number of items to display` if it is not available define it through CSS or javascript.

Comment: Can you let me know the CSS or Javascript? See the Website link above